# What can I "forward declare" in C++?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I know I can do

```
class Foo;
```

and probably

```
struct Bar;
```

and global functions

```
bool IsValid(int iVal);
```

What about a typed enum?  What about a typed enum within an undeclared class?  What about a function with an undeclared class?  What about a static member within an undeclared class?  What about these within an unknown namespace?  Am I missing anything else that can be forward declared?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: `extern int globalVar;` where globalVar is declared in a separate compilation unit.

Comment: enum is going to be able to forward declare in C++0x. and you cannot "partially" forward declare classes (forward declaration of methods)

Comment: I tend to put typed enums within the classes that "define" them.  I then run into "circular dependency" compiler issues with two classes that reference each other's enums.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can forward declare

- Templates, including partial specializations
- Explicit specializations
- Nested classes (this includes structs, "real" classes and unions)
- Non-nested and local classes
- Variables ("extern int a;")
- Functions

If by "forward declaration" you strictly mean "declare but not define" you can also forward declare member functions. But you cannot redeclare them in their class definition once they are declared. You cannot forward-declare enumerations. I'm not sure whether I missed something.

Please note that all forward declarations listed above, except partial and explicit specializations, need to be declared using an unqualified name and that member functions and nested classes can only be declared-but-not-defined in their class definition.

```
class A { };
class A::B; // not legal

namespace A { }
void A::f(); // not legal

namespace A { void f(); } // legal

class B { class C; }; // legal
class B::C; // declaration-only not legal

class D { template<typename T> class E; };
template<typename T> class D::E<T*>; // legal (c.f. 14.5.4/6)
```

Comment: I think your forgot the new `enum class` from C++0x. The point of precising the underlying representation was to make it forward-declarable if I recall correctly.

Comment: is there any point in forward-declaring a partial-specializaton? Partial specializations are not visible during name lookup, and are resolved at the point of instantiation of the template - at which point they must be completely defined anyway.

Comment: @willj it is permissible to have an undefined template in certain contexts (forward declared) without error, but doing an instantiation when the template is defined. ADL calls where the argument type is associated with the partial specialization is an example. Had you not forward declared it but already defined the primary template, the primary template would be instantiated instead.

Comment: @litb Can you give me an example? Question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200312/whats-the-point-of-forward-declaring-a-class-template-explicit-partial-speciali